# Hyperspectral Image Processing with Python

Tags: python, enthought

How do you read into memory a hyperspectral image (3d) using python's enthought canopy distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing [Spectral Python (Spy)](http://www.spectralpython.net/) is the best way to go:

```
C:\Users\Me> pip install spectral
```

Once you get the module installed, reading a hyperspectral image into memory can be readily accomplished by:

```
>>> import spectral
>>> img = spectral.open_image(<HSI_filename>)
```

Comment: Do this from a "Canopy Command Prompt" or "Canopy Terminal", opened from the Canopy Tools menu. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

install Spy package.
use ipython terminal.

```
ipython --pylab
```

to read to memory and view HSI:

```
from spectral import*
import numpy as np
var=open_image(r"C:\<give_image_file_location>")
img= var.load()    #save as ndarray
np.save(outimg, img)    #save image to a binary file in .npy format
imshow(var)   #view image in some bands
```